# How to ask Spring Batch to retry a failed step after some amount of time?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-retry

How can I ask Spring Batch to retry a failed step after some amount of time?

If the step fails more than x number of times, I would like to no longer retry the step and have the entire job fail.

I'm using Java Config and prefer to not to use XML to configure the retry.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/retry.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `Spring Batch` prior of version `2.2.0` then use the `Retry` [functionality included in the Spring Batch library](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/retry.html).

As noted in the beginning of the above quoted Spring Batch documentation page for Retry:

> *The retry functionality was pulled out of Spring Batch as of 2.2.0. It is now part of a new library, Spring Retry.*

Otherwise use directly the [Spring Retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry) directly (spinoff the Spring Batch project) that is adding some nice declarative way to annotate the functionality you need:

```
@Service
class MyService {
    //...
    @Retryable(maxAttempts=5, backoff=@Backoff(delay=100, maxDelay=500))
    public myFunctionalityService() {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. How can I apply this to a Spring Batch step?

Comment: Works after moving from 1.3.1.RELEASE to 1.4.0.RELEASE spring-boot-starter-batch

Answer (score 1):

It's all right here

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/retry.html

There are some implemented retry policies, but I think in your case you need to implement interface *RetryPolicy* so it will fit your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a good feature list, but it doesn't explain how to use it. Some examples would be nice.